# What does "unique modulo" mean?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

"The square root of a square number modulo 257 is unique modulo 257"
(This is something that I have to prove or invalidate)

I don't understand what 'is unique modulo 257' means?

Comment: Define  "square root"

Comment: x is the square root of x*x

Comment: So what is the "square root" of $\ 1 = 1*1 = (-1)*(-1)\equiv 256 * 256?\ $

Comment: I put up an answer, but Bill's comment made me realize that this statement doesn't really make sense if interpreted the way I interpreted it. So I removed the answer.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how to define square root in a "good" way, but for this problem x is a natural number that is not 0 so it couldn't be (-1)

Comment: But $\ -1\equiv 256\pmod{257}\ $

Comment: @vadim123 I put it back up because I realized this is a "prove or disprove" question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that if $x^2 \equiv z \pmod {257}$ and $y^2 \equiv z \pmod {257}$ then $x \equiv y \pmod {257}$.

Generally "a thing with property X is unique modulo ..." means that if two things have property X (in this case, their square is equivalent to the same number mod 257) then they are equivalent in whatever the equivalence relation following the word "modulo" is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm trying to understand it. If x^2 and y^2 are equivalent to the same number mod 257, would that mean that x^2 = y^2?

Comment: @Capucine No, "equivalent to the same number mod 257" means that they give the same remainder when you try to divide them by 257. For example $1 \equiv 5 \pmod 4$.

Comment: @Capucine   It is a little hard to tell from your question... modulo odd primes, square roots come in $\pm$ pairs. In particular, the square roots of $-1$ are $16, 241 \pmod {257},$ as $16^2 = 256 \equiv -1 \pmod {257}.$ There is typically a unique pair... Note $241^2 + 1 = 257 \cdot 226$

Comment: @Ian Oh thank you! I think I understand now :)

Comment: @WillJagy I forgot to say that x must be a natural number, so it can't be -1 or any other negative number. My mistake!

Comment: @Capucine Are you sure you understand? Do you think that the claim in the  first sentence in your answer is correct?

Comment: @Capucine I suspect the writers of the question actually intend for you to invalidate the statement through just the sort of example that Bill has been alluding to. Perhaps it's invalid in your context for you to refer to the $\pm$ pairs in that exact fashion, but keep in mind that mod $n$, $-1$ and $n-1$ are equivalent...

Comment: I did invalidate the claim, with x=250 and y=7 (if I understand it correctly?).

Comment: @Capucine Yes, that one will do the job (since 250 is equivalent to -7).

Comment: @Ian Thanks! I'm trying to understand what you mean when you say "mod n, −1 and n−1 are equivalent"?  Something like 9mod4 -1=0 and (9-1)mod4=0?

Comment: $-1 \equiv 7 \pmod 4$ for example.

Comment: @Ian I see, thanks!